# top k along last dimension of a (batch, 13, 13, 3, 1) tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

The tensor shape is `(batch_size, 13, 13, 3, 1)`, where the last dimension is the objectness score. How to keep only the top_k objectness scores without messing around with the tensor (making everything zero in the last dimension if it is not in top-k).

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide some of your attempts even if they failed.

Comment: So `tf.reduce_max(array, reduction_indices=-1)` and slicing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tf.math.top_k](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/top_k)

```
tf.math.top_k(tensor, k= top_k_value)
```

To put everything in the last dimension to 0, you can consider using the following:

```
tf.mul(tensor, tf.constant([0]))
```

With the latter, you will end up having all the elements of your tensor being 0